# Sessão em banco de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, escalabilidade

Pensando sobre a escalabilidade das aplicações desenvolvidas em [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), pesquisei sobre alternativas para não usar "sessão em memória".

Vi que é possível salvar os dados da sessão em banco de dados e usar o SQL Server como servidor de estado, mas também vi que existe o ASP.NET State Service, que é um serviço do Windows que serve exclusivamente para gerenciar o ambiente de Sessão do ASP.NET.

Qual destas alternativas é recomendada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende do que sua aplicação precisa. A pergunta "qual alternativa é recomendada" é muito categórica, então não vou respondê-la diretamente. Vou falar um pouco sobre cada modelo e você deverá decidir qual é mais interessante:

- **In process**: é o padrão, a sessão fica armazenada dentro do processo do Application Pool. Se você tem apenas um servidor web ou se o estado da sessão não é importante (o cliente ser redirecionado para outro servidor, por exemplo), então esta é uma boa opção
- **State server**: você utiliza outro servidor para manter o estado da sessão. Permite que você tenha N servidores de aplicação compartilhando as mesmas sessões, permitindo que um cliente seja roteado para diferentes servidores entre as requisições sem que ele perceba. Porém, a sessão continua em memória. Se houver alguma falha no servidor, ela será perdida. Este risco também ocorre no primeiro modelo.
- **SQL Server**: as sessões são persistidas em uma tabela. Permite que você tenha N servidores de aplicação compartilhando as mesmas sessões. Como a sessão está persistida, ela será mantida mesmo que haja falha nos servidores. Contudo, esta opção é mais lenta que o State Server, porque há o custo do banco de dados. Além disso, as sessões ficam todas em um tabelão, o que pode ser um problema se você tiver um volume muito alto de usuários.

Eu *acho* que, para o seu caso, o mais recomendado é o State server.